# What is a good way to "rotate" (circular shift) a two dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, language-agnostic, swap

This is really a conceptual (language-agnostic) question, but for the sake of explanation, I'll use C++. I'd prefer an answer that can be ported to other languages (no pointer arithmetic or memory tricks).

---

Let's say we have:

- `arr`, our **rectangular** 2D array of some  arbitrary type `T`
- `void shift(int dx, int dy)`, the function that performs the "rotation"
- `numRows`, the number of rows
- `numCols`, the number of columns

`shift()` shifts the array such that all rows are moved down `dx` places, and the rows pushed out of bounds will wrap-around to the beginning. (Likewise for the columns and `dy`.) Let's say this is what our array looks like initially:

```
{{a1, a2, a3, a4},
 {b1, b2, b3, b4},
 {c1, c2, c3, c4},
 {d1, d2, d3, d4}};
```

After we call our function: `shift(2,1)`, `arr` should look like this:

```
{{c4, c1, c2, c3},
 {d4, d1, d2, d3},
 {a4, a1, a2, a3},
 {b4, b1, b2, b3}};
```

In this case, `dx` was **2**, so everything moved **down** two places, and `dy` was **1**, so everything also moved to the **right** one place.

Here was my approach to solving this problem:

```
void shift(int dx, int dy)
{
   T newArr[numRows][numCols];
   for(int r = 0; r < numRows; r++)
   {
      for(int c = 0; c < numCols; c++)
         newArr[(r + dx) % numRows][(c + dy) % numCols] = arr[r][c];
   }
   for(int r = 0; r < numRows; r++)
   {
      for(int c = 0; c < numCols; c++)
         arr[r][c] = newArr[r][c];
   }
}
```

I'm not satisfied with this code because it is neither time-efficient nor space-efficient. I'm looking for a more elegant solution that does more with fewer loops *and* uses less memory.

Comment: I don't understand why do you need  4 for-loops to solve this. Can you show your code?

Comment: @IvanGritsenko Sorry if this is late, but I've updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility would be to not move the elements at all. The idea would be to have a function that transforms the index(es) used in such a way that the original array **appears** rotated.

You get a slight performance hit by wrapping the original array in an appropriate data type. But whenever you rotate (or mirror, or reverse, or whatever) you gain in terms of memory and time.

Comment: The point of `shift()` is to mutate the data structure permanently, so any future addressing of `arr` will automatically retrieve the newly placed element.

One way to implement your idea is to change `T arr[n][m]` to `T* arr[n][m]`, and simply change what the pointers are pointing to. In heap-allocation-only languages like Java, it's what happens by default.

While this does reduce the space complexity quite a bit, it's still O(n\*m), because n\*m pointers are stored in the temporary array.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    const int nrows = 4, ncols = 5;
    const int dx = 2, dy = 1;
    int a[nrows ][ncols] = { {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 
        { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 },
        { 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 }
    };
    int tmp[nrows][ncols];
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
            tmp[(i + dx) % nrows][(j + dy) % ncols] = a[i][j];
    memcpy(a, tmp, sizeof(tmp));
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
            printf(j < ncols - 1 ? "%3d " : "%3d\n", a[i][j]);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/MKDYav).

Alternative approach using memory copying is specific to `c++`. This is possible due to a method of storing multidimensional arrays in memory in `c++` which is contiguous. Last elements of a row are followed by the first elements of the next ones.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    const int nrows = 4, ncols = 5;
    const int dx = 2, dy = 1;
    int a[nrows][ncols] = { {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 },
        { 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 }
    };
    int tmp[nrows][ncols];
    memcpy(tmp + dx, a, (nrows - dx) * ncols * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(tmp, a + (nrows - dx), dx * ncols * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(a, tmp, sizeof(tmp));
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
        memcpy(tmp[i] + dy, a[i], (ncols - dy) * sizeof(int));
        memcpy(tmp[i], a[i] + ncols - dy, dy * sizeof(int));
    }

    memcpy(a, tmp, sizeof(tmp));
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
            printf(j < ncols - 1 ? "%3d " : "%3d\n", a[i][j]);
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/TzU8YBS4).

Comment: The first solution is better because it's more portable, but the space complexity is very high if the array is not made of pointers or primitives.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a lower level function that efficiently copy sublocks of Matrix (which deals with low level memory arrangement, row-major column-major ordering etc...), the operation can conceptually be decomposed in 4 subblock copies. Using matlab array notations and 1-based array indexing, that is something like:

```
tmp(1:nr , 1:nc) = a(end-nr+1:end , end-nc+1:end );
tmp(1:nr , nc+1:end) = a(end-nr+1:end , 1:end-nc );
tmp(nr+1:end , 1:nc) = a(1:end-nr , end-nc+1:end );
tmp(nr+1:end , nc+1:end) = a(1:end-nr , 1:end-nc );
```

Note that the assumption of letting low level functions do the low level job is very common (like BLAS and LAPACK for example).

Answer (score 0):

```
void scroll_left(int Array[8][8])
{
  for (u=0; u<8; u++)
  {
    for(int r=0; r<8; r++)
    {
      for (int c=0; c<8; c++)
      temp[r][c]=A[r][(c+u)%8];
    }
    delay_1(1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using O(1) auxiliary space in a few ways. All of these are adaptations of algorithms to rotate one-dimensional arrays. To keep the descriptions/notation simple, I'll assume `dx` and `dy` are positive and assume you can figure out what to do if they're negative.

#### Simple, slow solution for small dx, dy

There is a very simple algorithm to rotate a one-dimensional array by 1 step in linear time: store the last element in a temporary variable, shift the rest of the elements to the right by one, then write the temporary variable to the first position in the array.

This can be straightforwardly adapted to rotate a 2D array by 1 step horizontally, or vertically, and with a bit of extra work, diagonally. So you can either apply `dx` horizontal rotations and `dy` vertical rotations; or you can do `min(dx, dy)` diagonal rotations, then `max(dx, dy) - min(dx, dy)` orthogonal rotations.

This takes `O(numRows * numCols * (dx + dy))` time, so it's not suitable for large shifts. However, if you're only ever shifting by one space, then it's not just fine; it's optimal.

#### Cycle decomposition

Let `a` be the [GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of `numRows` and `dx`, and `b` be the GCD of `numRows` and `dy`. Then the desired rotation will permute the array in `a * b` independent cycles of length `numCols * numRows / (a * b)`. The GCDs can be computed in logarithmic time by [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

For `i = 0 to a - 1`, and `j = 0 to b - 1`, use the temporary-variable approach to rotate the cycle starting at `arr[j][i]` by one step. This cycle consists of the elements `arr[j][i]`, then `arr[j + dy][i + dx]`, then `arr[j + 2*dy][i + 2*dx]`, and so on, where the indices are computed modulo `numRows` and `numCols` respectively.

The time complexity is `O(numRows * numCols)`, because each array component is only read from once and only written to once. However, the algorithm's performance can be degraded for two reasons: it does a lot of modulo operations (bad when the array dimensions aren't powers of 2), and the consecutive reads/writes are not in adjacent array locations (bad when the whole array doesn't fit in cache).

#### Reverse subarrays

A one-dimensional array of length `n` can be rotated `k` steps to the right by the following algorithm:

- Reverse the whole array,
- Reverse the subarray `0 .. k-1`,
- Reverse the subarray `k .. n-1`.

We can perform a 2D rotation by rotating the rows by `dx`, and then rotating the columns by `dy`.

This algorithm reads and writes each array component four times, so its time complexity is also `O(numRows * numCols)`, but it does more passes over the array than the algorithm using cycle decomposition. However, it does no modulo operations, and it may have fewer cache misses. It is also simpler to implement.